# $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ if and only if $2$ generates $\mathbb{F}_p^{*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I need to show the equivalence:

> $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$ if and only if $2$ generates $\mathbb{F}_p^{*}$.

Maybe I should clarify the meaning of "generates": $\mathbb{F}_p^{*}$ is a cyclic group (as the mulplicitive group of a finite field) composed of the elements $1, 2, ...., p-1$, and $2$ generates $\mathbb{F}_p^{*}$ means that all elements are its powers.

I tried what seems to be, intuitively the easy direction. Here's my attempt:
Suppose $1+x+...+x^{p-1}$ is irreducible. Let $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_2$ be a root of the polynomial. Then $[\mathbb{F}_2[\alpha]: \mathbb{F}_2]=p-1$ thus $\mathbb{F}_2[\alpha]\cong \mathbb{F}_{2^{p-1}}$.
Now I'm stuck. I think it might have something to do with the multiplcitive group of this field, since it's order is $2^{p-1}-1$ who's divisable be $p$, but maybe I'm wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: The zeros of that polynomial are roots of unity of order $p$. If $2$ generates $\Bbb{F}_p^*$, then all those roots can be gotten from each other by repeated squaring. In other words they are conjugates to each other over $\Bbb{F}_2$ (squaring = Frobenius). The converse also holds. I have given this argument too many times on our site in many guises. Leaving the search of dupes for somebody else

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I tried to follow your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if $\alpha$ is a $p$th root of unity, then $\alpha^{n} = \alpha$ iff $n \equiv 1 \bmod p$.
- if the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $D$, then $\alpha^{2^m} = \alpha$ iff $D | m$.
- let $r$ be the least integer such that $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{2^r}$. Then $\sigma(a) = a^2$ is the Frobenius automorphism and generates $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{2^r}/\mathbb{F}_{2})$, which means that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $$\phi(x) = \prod_{k=1}^d (x-\sigma^k(a))=\prod_{k=1}^d (x-a^{2^k})$$
  where $d = [\mathbb{F}_{2}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{2}]$, which is also the least integer such that $\alpha = \alpha^{2^d}$ i.e. the order of $2$ modulo $p$.
- if $d = p-1$, since $\alpha$ is a root of $\varphi(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} x^m$, then $\phi = \varphi$. Conversely, if $d \ne p-1$ then $\phi | \varphi$ which is not irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We haven't learned about the Galois group yet so the only thing I don't understand is where did $\phi$ come from and why is it the minimal polynomial. Apart from that everything is clear.

Comment: @35T41 Sorry, I'm using that : $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}/\mathbb{F}_q$ is a Galois extension, so the minimal polynomial of $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ is $\prod_{\gamma \in E} (x-\gamma)$ where $E$ is the orbit of $\beta$ under the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}/\mathbb{F}_q$, and that this group is cyclic and generated by the [Frobenius automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism#As_a_generator_of_Galois_groups) $\sigma(a)  = a^q$.

Comment: @35T41 Ask Jykri if he knows a more elementary proof, and explain what you know

Comment: This is the approach I would recommend. You can also do it as follows. The field $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ has an element of (multiplicative) order $p$ if and only if $p\mid (2^m-1)$. The minimal polynomial of the said element has degree  that is the smallest positive $m$ with that property. That minimal polynomial is irreducible, so...

Comment: @35T41 See Jyrki elementary approach : all we need is that $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $2^m-1$. If $p | 2^m-1$ then there is $a \in \mathbb{F}_{2^m}, a\ne 1$ such that $a^p = 1$, hence it is a root of $x^p-1$ and of $1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{p-1}$.

Comment: OK, now I can finally fully understand the proof :)